# how to Create a Socket webservice api between two parties in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, sockets

I'm using database- mongoDB, Server - Node.js and sockets for transferring messages.

I need to develop a communication between Agent chat with Customer chat.In current scenario, 
Chat between agents is possible. How should I create communication between Agent chat and Customer chat (one to many)?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement database updates, Pub/Sub channels and push notifications? That's super broad... I doubt if this is would be a valid question for SO.

Comment: yes , can i create sockets acts as a web service.I want to update in database also

Comment: Yes, you can probably use AJAX or Websockets (or both) for this API. You will need to use a database to store any updates and use a Pub/Sub service (i.e. Redis) to push the updates to any connected clients. To utilize push notifications to a web page, websockets are probably a good solution. There are many ways to do what you ask, your question is too broad. I suggest you read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide...

Comment: I'm using database- mongoDB, Server - Node.js and sockets for transferring messages.

I need to develop a communication between Agent chat to Customer chat.In current scenario, Chat between agents is possible. How should I create communication between Agent chat and Customer chat (one to many)?